# Simulate Oracle Index Without Creating It

Tags: oracle, indexing, virtual, explain

Is there a way for me to test a new index (i.e. in memory?) without actually creating it yet? I would like to test it out and see if the Explain Plan is better before I hand off the index creation to the DBA.

My database is Oracle 12c.

Comment: I'm surprised the DBA is not determining which indexes are appropriate.

Comment: Creating a fake/mini version of an index may just give you misleading results. Getting a better plan depends on letting the optimizer work with real statistics based on a real data volume and distribution. So, if it's so small you would create it in memory, it's cheap enough to create it for real and really test it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm *not surprised* - the index necessity depends on the *applications* that are not always the main focus of DBA's... The dynamic SQL produced from diverses ORM's etc. makes this not easier.

Comment: Good approach, but please also *run* the query, only comparing costs of execution plans doensn't mean the query realy executed better...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with 11g Oracle prepared exact for this reason *inivisible indexes* - the basic idea is simple.

You created a new indes as *inivisible*. i.e. no other session will see it and will not get possible negative sideffects (note that contrary to a popular belief *more indixes means better performance* - a new index can *ruin the performence of some queries*).

So only session that sets `OPTIMIZER_USE_INVISIBLE_INDEXES` can use and test the *invisible* index. Only after you are sure there are no negative effect, you  can `ALTER` the index as *visible*.

See [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/invisible-indexes-11gr1)  for more details

Comment: Doesn't this still incur overhead for maintaining the index for inserts and updates?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, this is helpful information.

Answer (score 1):

Plain answer: NO. Invisible indexes still need to be created on storage Location - not Memory,
Create a subset of your data in the same way it is stored - i.e. same tablespace, storage Location etc. to reduce time for creating it. Unfortunatly this is not a 100% solution. Ask your DBA if there are times where DB not used heavily and create the index during that slot.